# Module 'networkx' has no attribute 'blockmodel'?

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I'm trying to use the networkx blockmodel function, but Python keeps saying there is no attribute 'blockmodel'. I am using the example code in the documentation in the link [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.block.blockmodel.html?highlight=blockmodel#networkx.algorithms.block.blockmodel).

I do have networkx installed, and many other functions are working. Only this one seems to complain. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `blockmodel` function has been replaced in the latest version of networkx (you are looking at older documentation) with `quotient_graph`.
Here is an example of generating a blockmodel

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(6)
>>> partition = [{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}]
>>> M = nx.quotient_graph(G, partition, relabel=True)
>>> list(M.edges())
[(0, 1), (1, 2)]
```

See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.quotient_graph.html?highlight=blockmodel 
for the updated documentation.